# Vakil Exercise 1.2.B: Automorphism group is group

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

> If $A$ is an object in a category $\mathscr{C}$, show that the invertible elements of Mor$(A, A)$ form a group.

Since Vakil never mentioned (so far) what an invertible element is (he did define isomorphism and automorphism) I suppose it just means an isomorphism? I.e. $f : A \rightarrow B$ is invertible if there is a morphism $g : B \rightarrow A$ such that $f \circ g = \text{id}_{B}$ and $g \circ f = \text{id}_{A}$.

So then if $f, g$ are invertible morphisms in Mor$(A, A)$, then there are $\bar{f}: A \rightarrow A$, $\bar{g}: A \rightarrow A$ such that $f \circ \bar{f} = \text{id}_{A}$ and $\bar{f} \circ f = \text{id}_{A}$; similarly, for $g$ such that $g \circ \bar{g} = \text{id}_{A}$ and $\bar{g} \circ g = \text{id}_{A}$. But then $f \circ g$ is invertible since $f \circ g \circ \bar{g} \circ \bar{f} = f \circ \text{id}_{A} \circ \bar{f} = f \circ \bar{f} = \text{id}_{A}$ and $g \circ f \circ \bar{f} \circ \bar{g} = g \circ \text{id}_{A} \circ \bar{g} = g \circ \bar{g} = \text{id}_{A}$. Hence, invertible elements are closed.

Associativity of $\circ$ follows from the definition of a category and also the existence of an identity element follows from the definition of a category and we have $\text{id}_{A} \circ \text{id}_{A} = \text{id}_{A}$.

And invertibility of $f$ is trivially assumed.

Therefore, the invertible elements of Mor$(A, A)$ form a group.

Comment: Yep that looks good, and yes invertible means isomorphism here. Perhaps you should consider $\operatorname{Mor}(A,A)$ as a monoid, since this is always true, and it's always true that the invertible elements of a monoid form a group.

Comment: Thanks. While I was searching for the definition of an inverse in a category, I came across this website called nLab. Is it a good resource for category theory?

Comment: nLab is a good resource, but it should never be your only resource for anything (except standard proofs and definitions). It's useful because it's very encyclopedic, but it often suffers from missing motivation, and it's very opinionated. Definitely use it, but also look at other sources.